# update user information sequilze express

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to update a users information. User-created an account with only name email and password and I am trying to update the user information with other optional fields how do i check if the password is changed update the password if not use the old password in the database. I am using react in my frontend.I am using sequilize orm - mysql.How would i be able to do that.Its giving me an error when i even try to override the password with new one.Please help.Thanks

```
  router.post("/update", (req, res) => {
  const dataToday = new Date();
  const studentData = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
    about_me: req.body.about_me,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
    company: req.body.company,
    school: req.body.school,
    hometown: req.body.hometown,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    created: dataToday
  };
  console.log(studentData);

  Student_Info.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(student => {
      if (student) {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          studentData.password = hash;
          Student_Info.update(studentData)
            .then(student => {
              res.json({
                status: student.email + "updated"
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.send("error" + err);
            });
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          error: "No User Found"
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send("error" + err);
    });
});
```

Comment: What error does sequalize show to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about try use `compareSync`?

```
Student_Info.findOne({
  where: {
    email: req.body.email
  }
})
  .then(student => {
    if (!student) throw new Error("No User Found")

    // return true if old password equals new password
    const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, student.password)
    if (validPassword) throw new Error("Same Password")
    studentData.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
    return student.update(studentData)
  })
  .then(student => {
    res.json({
      status: student.email + "updated"
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.send("error" + err);
  });
```